# Visual Studio 22 Scaffolding MVC Controller With View & Entity Framework Not Aware of Areas

Tags: visual-studio-2022, asp.net-core-scaffolding

I have created a new .Net Core project using **Visual Studio 22**. Inside of my project I have created a new area (it was created successfully and works as expected).

Upon creating a new scaffolded item, all of the assets (controller & views) are created, however the code generated in my views is not aware of area they were created in.

For example my structure is `/Areas/Admin/Flags`

I can hit `/Admin/Flags/Index` just fine.

However, all of the links and form actions point to `/Flags/[Action]`

It's as if the scaffolding engine was not aware that I was creating these assets inside of an area.

Any ideas?

Comment: The controller is aware - it's go this decorator between namespace and class declaration: ```[Area("Admin")]```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `app.UseEndpoints` with `area` in the pattern is an early middleware extension in `/program.cs`. I added right below `app.UseAuthorization();`

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
      name: "areas",
      pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
});
```

It will automatically utilize the area in the route.

Also, don't forget to copy `_ViewImports.cshtml` into the root of the `/areas/[area]/Views` folder, else links won't be clickable.